# How loop over columns and calculate distance using lat and long in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe with lat and long of various areas in a city.

A subset of the dataframe:

```
structure(list(Locality = c("ADYAR", "AMBATTUR", "KOLATHUR", 
"AVADI", "AGARAM", "ANNA NAGAR WEST", "CHROMPET", "MADIPAKKAM", 
"MOGAPPAIR", "MYLAPORE"), Transactions = c(607, 569, 498, 409, 
103, 257, 303, 343, 316, 205), lon = c(80.2564957, 80.1547844, 
80.2121332, 80.0969511, 80.2294222, 80.2017906, 80.1461663, 80.1960832, 
80.1749627, 80.2676303), lat = c(13.0011774, 13.1143393, 13.1239583, 
13.1067448, 13.1116221, 13.0861782, 12.951611, 12.9647462, 13.0837224, 
13.0367914), Ambatturlon = c(80.15478, 80.15478, 80.15478, 80.15478, 
80.15478, 80.15478, 80.15478, 80.15478, 80.15478, 80.15478), 
    Ambatturlat = c(13.11434, 13.11434, 13.11434, 13.11434, 13.11434, 
    13.11434, 13.11434, 13.11434, 13.11434, 13.11434), Guindylon = c(80.22064, 
    80.22064, 80.22064, 80.22064, 80.22064, 80.22064, 80.22064, 
    80.22064, 80.22064, 80.22064), Guindylat = c(13.00666, 13.00666, 
    13.00666, 13.00666, 13.00666, 13.00666, 13.00666, 13.00666, 
    13.00666, 13.00666), OMRlon = c(80.22915, 80.22915, 80.22915, 
    80.22915, 80.22915, 80.22915, 80.22915, 80.22915, 80.22915, 
    80.22915), OMRlat = c(12.91261, 12.91261, 12.91261, 12.91261, 
    12.91261, 12.91261, 12.91261, 12.91261, 12.91261, 12.91261
    )), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
> 
> df
# A tibble: 10 x 10
   Locality        Transactions   lon   lat Ambatturlon Ambatturlat Guindylon Guindylat OMRlon OMRlat
   <chr>                  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
 1 ADYAR                    607  80.3  13.0        80.2        13.1      80.2      13.0   80.2   12.9
 2 AMBATTUR                 569  80.2  13.1        80.2        13.1      80.2      13.0   80.2   12.9
 3 KOLATHUR                 498  80.2  13.1        80.2        13.1      80.2      13.0   80.2   12.9
 4 AVADI                    409  80.1  13.1        80.2        13.1      80.2      13.0   80.2   12.9
 5 AGARAM                   103  80.2  13.1        80.2        13.1      80.2      13.0   80.2   12.9
 6 ANNA NAGAR WEST          257  80.2  13.1        80.2        13.1      80.2      13.0   80.2   12.9
 7 CHROMPET                 303  80.1  13.0        80.2        13.1      80.2      13.0   80.2   12.9
 8 MADIPAKKAM               343  80.2  13.0        80.2        13.1      80.2      13.0   80.2   12.9
 9 MOGAPPAIR                316  80.2  13.1        80.2        13.1      80.2      13.0   80.2   12.9
10 MYLAPORE                 205  80.3  13.0        80.2        13.1      80.2      13.0   80.2   12.9
>
```

Columns Ambatturlon, Ambatturlat, Guindylon etc are localities within the same city. I need to calculate the distance between each locality and the other localities as mentioned in the columns: (Ambatturlon, Ambatturlat), (Guindylon Guindylat), (OMRlon OMRlat).

I learnt that we can use distHaversine function from geosphere package for this.

I tried it for first locality using below code:

```
> df %>% 
+   rowwise() %>% 
+     mutate(disttoAmbattur = distHaversine(c(lon, lat), c(Ambatturlon, Ambatturlat)))
Source: local data frame [10 x 11]
Groups: <by row>

# A tibble: 10 x 11
   Locality        Transactions   lon   lat Ambatturlon Ambatturlat Guindylon Guindylat OMRlon OMRlat disttoAmbattur
   <chr>                  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>          <dbl>
 1 ADYAR                    607  80.3  13.0        80.2        13.1      80.2      13.0   80.2   12.9      16744.   
 2 AMBATTUR                 569  80.2  13.1        80.2        13.1      80.2      13.0   80.2   12.9          0.483
 3 KOLATHUR                 498  80.2  13.1        80.2        13.1      80.2      13.0   80.2   12.9       6309.   
 4 AVADI                    409  80.1  13.1        80.2        13.1      80.2      13.0   80.2   12.9       6326.   
 5 AGARAM                   103  80.2  13.1        80.2        13.1      80.2      13.0   80.2   12.9       8098.   
 6 ANNA NAGAR WEST          257  80.2  13.1        80.2        13.1      80.2      13.0   80.2   12.9       5984.   
 7 CHROMPET                 303  80.1  13.0        80.2        13.1      80.2      13.0   80.2   12.9      18139.   
 8 MADIPAKKAM               343  80.2  13.0        80.2        13.1      80.2      13.0   80.2   12.9      17245.   
 9 MOGAPPAIR                316  80.2  13.1        80.2        13.1      80.2      13.0   80.2   12.9       4050.   
10 MYLAPORE                 205  80.3  13.0        80.2        13.1      80.2      13.0   80.2   12.9      14975.   
>
```

I could do same manually but there are many such localities columns. Could someone let me know if I can loop through other localities and add a new column similar to disttoAmbattur for each lat long combination of all localities columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can gather all the lat and lon columns together in a vector and use `map2` to pass them in parrallel. Calculate `distHaversine` for each pair and add them as new columns in the original dataframe.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

lon_col <- grep('.lon', names(df), value = TRUE)
lat_col <- grep('.lat', names(df), value = TRUE)

df %>%
  bind_cols(map2_dfc(lon_col, lat_col, ~{
       newcol <- paste0('dist', sub('lon', '', .x))
       df %>% 
       rowwise() %>% 
       transmute(!!newcol := geosphere::distHaversine(c(lon, lat),
                             c(.data[[.x]], .data[[.y]])))
}))

# A tibble: 10 x 13
#   Locality        Transactions   lon   lat Ambatturlon Ambatturlat Guindylon Guindylat OMRlon OMRlat distAmbattur distGuindy distOMR
#   <chr>                  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>        <dbl>      <dbl>   <dbl>
# 1 ADYAR                    607  80.3  13.0        80.2        13.1      80.2      13.0   80.2   12.9    16744.         3937.  10296.
# 2 AMBATTUR                 569  80.2  13.1        80.2        13.1      80.2      13.0   80.2   12.9        0.483     13953.  23861.
# 3 KOLATHUR                 498  80.2  13.1        80.2        13.1      80.2      13.0   80.2   12.9     6309.        13090.  23599.
# 4 AVADI                    409  80.1  13.1        80.2        13.1      80.2      13.0   80.2   12.9     6326.        17437.  25935.
# 5 AGARAM                   103  80.2  13.1        80.2        13.1      80.2      13.0   80.2   12.9     8098.        11723.  22154.
# 6 ANNA NAGAR WEST          257  80.2  13.1        80.2        13.1      80.2      13.0   80.2   12.9     5984.         9085.  19548.
# 7 CHROMPET                 303  80.1  13.0        80.2        13.1      80.2      13.0   80.2   12.9    18139.        10140.   9995.
# 8 MADIPAKKAM               343  80.2  13.0        80.2        13.1      80.2      13.0   80.2   12.9    17245.         5373.   6823.
# 9 MOGAPPAIR                316  80.2  13.1        80.2        13.1      80.2      13.0   80.2   12.9     4050.         9906.  19934.
#10 MYLAPORE                 205  80.3  13.0        80.2        13.1      80.2      13.0   80.2   12.9    14975.         6101.  14440.
```

Comment: Ronak, I read that '!!' is used to ask R to execute a prior expression, So is "transmute(!!newcol := "asking R to use the output of newcol from the previous "paste0" line? And why do we need ':=' instead of just '=' in transmute.

Comment: So `:=` is used when you want to add a new column with a name which is stored in a variable. Using `!!` we evaluate the variable `newcol`.